# What string in AeDebug\Debugger attaches IDA Pro as a debugger?

Tags: debugging, crash, ida

I need to debug some binary crash using IDA Pro. What is the command-line in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger` value that starts IDA Pro attached to the crashed process ?

I looked in the command-line switches of IDA but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA Pro can set itself as a JIT debugger.

```
0) open or create a database for a win32 program
1) select win32 debugger and set it as default (Debugger/Switch debugger)
2) Install IDA as JIT: Debugger/Debugger Options -> Set as just in time debugger
```